# What exactly "loadMaps: true" on "gulp-sourcemaps" does, and when should I use it?

Tags: gulp, source-maps, gulp-sourcemaps

According to `gulp-sourcemaps` [description](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sourcemaps), it is possible to pass a `loadMaps: true` option to it.

The doc says that this "load existing source maps", but exactly, what does this mean?

Where these "existing" maps are supposed to be located? Are these the files already generated from a previous task run? Does that mean that if these are present in the destination fodler,they won't be re-generated?

Also, how can I determine if I should use this option or if I can safely ignore it?

Answer (score 1):

A little further down in the description you linked:

> Init Options
>
> - loadMaps
>
>   Set to true to load existing maps for source files. Supports the following:
>
>   ```
>   1. inline source maps
>   2. source map files referenced by a `sourceMappingURL=` comment
>   3. source map files with the same name (plus .map) in the same directory
>   ```